# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator; cannot replace

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am having trouble dealing with `Core Data` and using the `Parent/Child context method` for dealing with `multithreading with Core Data`.

This is the flow of my app in regards to Core Data and multithreading:

1. Receive JSON from server using Alamofire
2. Create background thread in Alamofire response and parse JSON
3. Parsed info gets converted into a `NSManagedObject` class (still in bg thread)
4. NSManagedObject class gets passed to my DatabaseManager class (still in bg thread)
5. DatabaseManager init creates a `Child Context` (still in bg thread), and sets the `Parent Context`
6. Updates object in Core Data with NSBatchUpdate
7. DatabaseManager `performBlock` and saves on both Child and Parent contexts

I received the error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.**

Sometimes I will make multiple calls to the server simultaneously. Could this be a related problem since `performBlock` will block the Parent context when it's trying to save (say from a different thread)?

From what I have read so far about using the `Parent/Child` context method for Core Data and multithreading, I have understood that basically when you try to save from a background thread, it will block the current child and parent context and save the changes. But what will happen if another background thread with a different child context tries to save at the same time?

Also a side note, in my `DatabaseManager` class, I have been using the Parent Context for fetch requests and Child Context for update requests. Would this pose a problem?

Here is my method that I use to fetch the single instance of the `Parent Context`:

```
// In my DatabaseManager class
lazy var parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
    }()

// In my AppDelegate
lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return managedObjectContext
}()
```

**DatabaseManager class init and saveContext methods:**

```
init(child: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    childContext = child
    childContext!.parentContext = parentContext
}

func saveContext() {
    if parentContext != nil && childContext != nil {
        childContext!.performBlock({
            var childError: NSError? = nil
            if self.childContext!.save(&childError) {
                println("Child context saved")

                self.parentContext!.performBlock({
                    var parentError: NSError? = nil
                    if self.parentContext!.save(&parentError) {
                        println("Parent context saved")
                    }
                    else {
                        println("Parent context saving error: \(parentError?.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }
            else {
                println("Child context saving error: \(childError?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Creation of the Child context in my HttpResponseManager which handles the response from the server call**

```
class HttpResponseManager {

let db: DatabaseManager?
lazy var parentContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    if let managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext {
        return managedObjectContext
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
    }()
let childContext: NSManagedObjectContext?

init() {
    childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    childContext!.parentContext = parentContext
    db = DatabaseManager(child: childContext!)
}

func handleGameInfo(json: JSON) {
    let arr = JSON(json[GlobalVars.kEventGameInfoGet].arrayObject!)

    for (index: String, obj: JSON) in arr {
        var game = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Game", inManagedObjectContext: self.childContext!) as Game

        game.id = obj[GlobalVars.kId].stringValue
        game.name = obj[GlobalVars.kName].stringValue
        game.platform = obj[GlobalVars.kPlatform].stringValue
        game.genre = obj[GlobalVars.kGenre].stringValue
        game.coverPhoto = (obj[GlobalVars.kCoverPhoto].arrayValue)[0].stringValue

        if db != nil {
            db!.updateGame(game)
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: is AppDelegate an only place where you set a persistent-store-coordinator to parent MOC?

Comment: @bluedome Yes. AppDelegate is the only place where I set the `parentContext.persistentStoreCoordinator`.

Comment: it seems that lazy property is not thread safe(http://nshacker.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/lazy-keyword-in-swift). but i couldn't find official statement about that. anyway, it may be better to access parent MOC in advance.